# Dynamic grid layout with variable-sized elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, grid-layout, masonry, gridstack

I know that this may be a frequent question but I didn't have any luck finding an answer.

I need to build a 3 column responsive layout for a grid containing an unknown number of variable-sized elements. Their size are limited to a maximum of 3x3 in the grid.

My problem here is that I need to be able to stack 1-row items, but every plugin that I tried ends up filling my rows before columns.

For example, here's a solution using *gridstack.js*:

```
<div class="grid-stack grid-stack-3">
  <div class="grid-stack-item" data-gs-width="1" data-gs-height="2" data-gs-auto-position="1">
    <div class="grid-stack-item-content" style="background: red;">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-stack-item" data-gs-width="1" data-gs-height="1" data-gs-auto-position="1">
    <div class="grid-stack-item-content" style="background: green;">2</div>
  </div>  
  <div class="grid-stack-item" data-gs-width="1" data-gs-height="1" data-gs-auto-position="1">
    <div class="grid-stack-item-content" style="background: green;">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-stack-item" data-gs-width="1" data-gs-height="2" data-gs-auto-position="1">
    <div class="grid-stack-item-content" style="background: red;">4</div>
  </div>
</div>

var options = {
  cell_height: 267,
  vertical_margin: 26,
  width: 3
};
$('.grid-stack').gridstack(options);
```

As you can see in the image, the green elements are not stacked as they should.

[image]

To have them stacked, I need to swap divs 3 and 4, leading to this (which is the expected layout).

[image]

Unfortunately, the items are received from an external service, so I can't control their order (and it would be pointless as I can't know which the expected layout will be).

I had a *little* luck with *Isotope*'s `fitColumn` mode, meaning that it fixes the example in the pictures, but adding a fifth element creates a fourth column and I'm forced to have just 3 of them, so I can't really use it.

Here's the HTML for the test layout that I need to implement (this one's a sample of what I've been asked to do):

```
<div class="grid-stack grid-stack-3">
  <div class="grid-stack-item" data-gs-width="1" data-gs-height="2" data-gs-auto-position="1">
    <div class="grid-stack-item-content" style="background: red;">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-stack-item" data-gs-width="1" data-gs-height="1" data-gs-auto-position="1">
    <div class="grid-stack-item-content" style="background: green;">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-stack-item" data-gs-width="1" data-gs-height="2" data-gs-auto-position="1">
    <div class="grid-stack-item-content" style="background: red;">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-stack-item" data-gs-width="1" data-gs-height="1" data-gs-auto-position="1">
    <div class="grid-stack-item-content" style="background: green;">3</div>
  </div>  
  <div class="grid-stack-item" data-gs-width="2" data-gs-height="3" data-gs-auto-position="1">
    <div class="grid-stack-item-content" style="background: blue;">5</div>
  </div>  
  <div class="grid-stack-item" data-gs-width="1" data-gs-height="2" data-gs-auto-position="1">
    <div class="grid-stack-item-content" style="background: red;">6</div>
  </div>  
  <div class="grid-stack-item" data-gs-width="1" data-gs-height="1" data-gs-auto-position="1">
    <div class="grid-stack-item-content" style="background: green;">7</div>
  </div>  
  <div class="grid-stack-item" data-gs-width="2" data-gs-height="1" data-gs-auto-position="1">
    <div class="grid-stack-item-content" style="background: yellow;">8</div>
  </div> 
  <div class="grid-stack-item" data-gs-width="1" data-gs-height="1" data-gs-auto-position="1">
    <div class="grid-stack-item-content" style="background: green;">9</div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Does someone have any idea on a javascript solution that allows me to build such a layout (support for one-column mode is required too!)? I'm running out of options and I'd like to avoid writing a custom solution for this task because I'm not that experienced with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Look at CSS `grid layout` as it has become [well supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid) in most browsers.  The [Grid by Example](https://gridbyexample.com/) site and [video playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQkVA6z3dFvbnBJetfYDAF3-cG_ubgdZR) will help.  CSS-Tricks also has a nice [article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

Comment: My issue is not how to build the grid, but it's related to how to optimally lay the items out. Your suggestion will still require me to manually assign a row/column to each item if I want to achieve the result layout.

Comment: Is the data that inconsistent? Does the  layout have to be calculated dynamically each time? There may be an existing library, maybe. Any chance [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) might help?

Comment: It is, and there's no pure css solution afaik. Flexbox, for example, still wraps item after filling the entire row, which is not what I'm looking for.